# Fill out the code for the addFullName function

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

Basic object problem I can't seem wrap my head around. I am sure I am over thinking it.
Fill out the code for the addFullName function. The function should:

> Take one input parameter, a person object.
>   Add a property called fullName to the person object when called. The new fullName property is set to the string 'firstName lastName' (one string, with a space between the two names)
>   Modify the object passed in without returning anything.

```
// an example `person` object
var person = {
    firstName: 'Joseph',
    lastName: 'Magnolia',
    ageInYears: 34
}

function addFullName(personObj) {
  /* your code here */
  person.fullName = personObj.firstName + ' ' + personObj.lastName;
}
```

Test results:

```
✗ it should set fullName property to 'Joseph Magnolia'
  Error:
    fullName does not equal 'Joseph Magnolia': expected undefined to deeply equal 'Joseph Magnolia'
✗ it should set fullName property to 'Michael Smith'
  Error:
    fullName does not equal 'Michael Smith': expected undefined to deeply equal 'Michael Smith'
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be personObj.fullName = personObj.firstName + ' ' + personObj.lastName? Notice the *Obj*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was real close, you just had to use the variable/object passed as an argument to the function. The argument is called `personObj` and should be used inside the function to work for any Person Object passed to the function.

```js
// an example `person` object
var person = {
    firstName: 'Joseph',
    lastName: 'Magnolia',
    ageInYears: 34
}

function addFullName(personObj) {
  // You want to use the variable/object passed to the function
  personObj.fullName = personObj.firstName + ' ' + personObj.lastName;
}

addFullName(person);
alert('Joseph Magnolia' === person.fullName);
```

**ES6 Improvement**

If you use ES6 you could use template strings:

```
function addFullName(personObj) {
  // You want to use the variable/object passed to the function
  personObj.fullName = `${personObj.firstName} ${personObj.lastName}`;
}
```